# The boundary of an $n$-manifold is an $n-1$-manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

The following problem is from the book "Introduction to topological manifolds".

Suppose $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary.
Show that the boundary of $M$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold (without boundary) when endowed with the subspace topology.

So far I’ve manged to prove that the boundary is a second countable Hausdorff space (when endowed with the subspace topology) but I’m stuck with proving it's locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}.$

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Let $x\in\partial M$ be any point on the boundary of $M$. Since $M$ is a manifold with boundary, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ that is homeomorphic to an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb H^n=\{ x\in\mathbb R^n : x_n\ge 0\}$ via a homeomorphism $\phi: U\to V$. Since $x\in\partial M$ we know that $\phi(x)\in V\cap\partial\mathbb H^n$, i.e. $(\phi(x))_n=0$. Since $\phi:U\to V$ is a homeomorphism, it restricts to a homeomorphism
$$\phi^{-1}(V\cap\partial\mathbb H^n) \to V\cap\partial\mathbb H^n.$$
We know that $V\cap\partial\mathbb H^n$ is open in the subspace topology on $\partial\mathbb H^n$ since $V$ is open in $\mathbb H^n$. Thus $V\cap\partial\mathbb H^n$ is an open neighborhood of $\phi(x)$ in $\partial\mathbb H^n$.

Now the open neighborhood $U\cap \partial M$ of $x$ in $\partial M$ is exactly $\phi^{-1}(V\cap\partial\mathbb H^n)$, which as we showed, is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\partial\mathbb H^n\cong\mathbb R^{n-1}$.

---

**On $\partial M$:** The most simple definition of $\partial M$ would be the set of all points of $M$ that don't have open neighborhoods which are isomorphic to open sets in $\mathbb R^n$. This gives you that any coordinate chart $\phi:U\to V$ of a manifold with a boundary has to send points of $\partial M$ to points of $\partial \mathbb H^n=\{x\in\mathbb H^n : x_n=0\}$, since all other points in $\mathbb H^n$ have open neighborhoods in $\mathbb R^n$ which can be pulled back to open neighborhoods in $M$ via $\phi$.

Another definition would be that $\partial M$ consists of all points of $M$ that are mapped to points of $\partial\mathbb H^n$ via all (or equivalently one) coordinate chart.

Comment: Why is $\phi(x)\in V\cap\partial\mathbb H^n$?

Comment: How do you define $\partial M$?

Comment: It's the topological boundary. Or am i missing something?

Comment: For a topological space $X$, the topological boundary $\partial X$ is empty, since $X$ is open and closed. By that definition $\partial M$ would be empty. Hint: One possible definition involves the boundary of $\mathbb H^n$ which is defined as $\{x\in\mathbb H^n : x_n=0\}$

Comment: I added a paragraph explaining two possible definitions of $\partial M$. Feel free to check their equivalence.

Comment: It's not clear why $\phi^{-1}(V\cap\partial\Bbb H^n)$ is equal to $U\cap\partial M$.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena, this follows from the definition of boundary points of $M$. A point of $M$ is a boundary point *if and only if* it is mapped to $\partial\mathbb H^n$ by any chart.

Comment: @Christoph but it's not clear why if a point is sent to $\partial\Bbb H^n$ by one chart, then it must belong to $\partial M$.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena Consider two charts $\varphi,\psi\colon U\to\mathbb H^n$, by definition, $\psi\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism $\varphi(U)\to\psi(U)$ sending $\varphi(x)$ to $\psi(x)$. For $x\in U$ you can now verify that $\varphi(x)\in\partial\mathbb H^n \Leftrightarrow \varphi(U)\setminus\{\varphi(x)\}$ is simply connected $\Leftrightarrow \psi(U)\setminus\{\psi(x)\}$ is simply connected $\Leftrightarrow$ $\psi(x)\in\partial\mathbb H^n$. Hence, either none or all charts send $x$ to $\partial\mathbb H^n$.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena This is a consequence of Brouwer invariance of domain theorem. If one chart sends $x$ to $\partial \Bbb H^n$, then every other chart in the neighborhood of $x$ does the same.

Comment: I came here to see if the proof depended on Brouwer's invariance of domain theorem. If it does, as these comments seems to imply, then the dependence should be explained in the answer.

Comment: I don't think it does. It only depends on $\mathbb H^n\setminus \{z\}$ being contractible if and only if $z\in\partial\mathbb H^n$, which I think can be proven without invariance of domain. (In my earlier comment replace "simply connected" by "contractible".)

Comment: Sorry for replying to this old post, but I got a similar question and I need to show that, if the chart is even a diffeomorphism, the restriction is a diffeomorphism as well. Maybe you can take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3750805/47771.

Answer (score 2):

A point in an $n$-manifold $M$ with boundary is by definition either contained in an open set homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ or homeomorphic to the upper half plane $\mathbb R^n_{\ge 0} = \{ (x_1, ... , x_n) | x_n \ge 0 \}$. The boundary points $u$ in $M$ are precisely the points contained in an open set homeomorphic to the upper half plane. From this you can show (by a contradiction argument) that $u$ must have coordinates of the form $u = (u_1, ..., u_{n-1}, 0)$.

To finish the proof it only remains to be shown that $u$ has a neighbourhood  $N$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. To this end note that if $N$ is any neighbourhood it contains an open set that is homeomorphic to an open set $U$ in the upper half plane. Let $f$ denote a homeomorphism between $U$ and the open set containing $u$.

Note that $B = \{(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, 0) | x_i \in \mathbb R \}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ and that it is a subspace of the upper half plane. Since $U$ is open in the upper half plane it follows that $U \cap B$ is open in $B$. To conclude the proof it is enough to note that $f(U \cap B)$ is open in $\partial M$ and contains $u$.