# Non-compact manifold with compact boundary

Tags: manifolds

What is an example of a non-compact manifold with compact boundary?

Comment: You just asked a very similar question – where are these questions coming from?

Comment: A book I'm reading just mention that these two things could happen without stating the examples. Should I have posted both in the same thread?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that $[0;\infty)$ is the required example.

Answer (score 3):

A non-compact manifold without boundary would work, as the empty set is compact.

Comment: A non-compact manifold, you mean.

Comment: Yep, edited. \{      \}

Answer (score 2):

Another example: take your favorite non-compact manifold without boundary, and remove an open ball from it.  Then the boundary of the result is a sphere.

Comment: That seems very nice. Could one say that removing a finite sum of open balls with finite radius from an arbitrary unbounded manifold creates all possible non-compact manifolds with compact boundary?

Comment: Or maybe we have to say a finite sum of open subsets with finite extend.

Comment: A general construction could be: in a noncompact manifold, find a compact submanifold-with-boundary $S$, and then remove the interior of $S$.  What remains has the same boundary as $S$, and that boundary is compact.  It's not clear to me whether all answers to the original question arise this way.

Comment: Ah, the answer is no: from [Any N dimensional manifold as a boundary of some N+1 dimensional manifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685531/any-n-dimensional-manifold-as-a-boundary-of-some-n1-dimensional-manifold/685569#685569), it's clear that $M = \Bbb{R}P^2 \times [0, \infty)$ cannot be obtained by removing the interior of a compact submanifold, since $\Bbb{R}P^2$ is not the boundary of any 3-manifold.  However, $M$ does satisfy the original question.