# Tangent space is independent of the coordiante function. Why $d\phi_0=d\psi_0\circ dh_0$ implies $Im(d\phi)\subseteq Im(d\psi)$

Tags: differential-topology, tangent-spaces

Tangent space is independent of the coordiante function.

Let $X$ be a smooth n-manifold and $\phi: U\to X$ be a local parametrization at $x$ ($\phi(0)=x$). Define tangent space as $T_x(X)=d\phi_0(\mathbb R^n)$

We claim tangent space is independent of the local parametrization so we take another local parametrization $\psi: V\to X$ and we shrink $U,V$ such that $\phi(U)=\psi(V)$ namely we take a diffeomorphism $h=\psi^{-1}\circ \phi:U\to V$

Such that $\phi=\psi\circ h$ and differentiating it yields:$$d\phi_0=d\psi_0\circ dh_0$$

Question: Why last equation would imply image of $d\psi$ consists image of $d\phi$?

Comment: Plus what a confusing book, never gives proper definitions, never gives enough and proper explanations...

Comment: I think it is a wonderful book pedagogically speaking, but not a proper encyclopedic text. This might be helpful, too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970219/prove-that-h-x-x-does-not-depend-on-the-choice-of-local-parametrization/2794375#2794375

Comment: I do not know what book you're talking about, but if you're trying to learn this material, it is assumed that you *know* and understand basic linear algebra and multivariable analysis (including the inverse function theorem). It is an elementary exercise to show that when $f=g\circ h$, then the image of $f$ is a subset of the image of $g$. You should not blame the book here; you should learn the background material first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To spell it out, if $x\in\operatorname{im}(d\phi_0)$, then $x=d\phi_0(y)$ for some $y$, and so $x=(d\psi_0\circ dh_0)(y)=(d\psi_0)(dh_0(y))$ is in $\operatorname{im}(d\psi_0)$. That is, $\operatorname{im}(d\phi_0)\subset\operatorname{im}(d\psi_0)$.

Also, you may want to check out J. Milnor's *Topology from the differentiable viewpoint* for what I find to be a clear exposition.