# Boundary of a manifold is a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, morse-theory

I was reading in the book Morse Theory and Floer Homology by Audin and Damian (translated in english) that the boundary of a manifold is not always a submanifold. I cannot see why that is true. Any explanations or an example of such a case would be great.

I am using the definitions of manifold and submanifold from Jeffrey Lee's Manifolds and Differential Geometry.

Comment: Boundary has two different meanings. In differential geometry, $(0,1)$ is a manifold without boundary. (After all, it is the same manifold as $\mathbb R$...)

Comment: I don't understand. Page 538, the authors write "The boundary, denoted by ∂V, is a submanifold of dimension n − 1." Where do they say otherwise?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554156/the-boundary-of-an-n-manifold-is-an-n-1-manifold) should help you answer your question.

Comment: @PseudoNeo pg100 - "It is however not completely true $\partial M$ is a submanifold of M."

Comment: @RayX Thanks, that helped. So the boundary is indeed a submanifold. I am guessing that maybe the author wanted to be really careful for the construction that followed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the book in front of me, but the authors might mean that the boundary (in the topological sense) of a submanifold  need not be a submanifold. For example, an open square $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but its boundary is not a smooth submanifold, as it has corners (you can easily get topological counterexamples, by for example removing $\{0\}\times(\frac 12,1)$ from the open square).